# Convert json string to array in php

Tags: arrays, json, string, curl

Im using curl the retrieve a json string from a log file. I was able to retrieve the string but it comes in this format.

```
[{"candy":"lollipop","timestamp":1385504260,"color":"red"}]
[{"candy":"laffytaffy","timestamp":1385504260,"color":"blue"}]
```

When i try to convert it to an array using decode, its as if decode isn't working. I was hoping someone could assist me in figuring this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this json seems to be wrong. It should has this format.

```
[{"candy":"lollipop","timestamp":1385504260,"color":"red"},
 {"candy":"laffytaffy","timestamp":1385504260,"color":"blue"}]
```

Maybe it's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

@Carlos is right your JSON is invalid. You have 2 separate arrays instead of an array of objects.

It should look like this instead:

```
[
    {
        "candy": "lollipop",
        "timestamp": 1385504260,
        "color": "red"
    },
    {
        "candy": "laffytaffy",
        "timestamp": 1385504260,
        "color": "blue"
    }
]
```

Try like this

```
<?php
$jsonData = '[{"candy":"lollipop","timestamp":1385504260,"color":"red"},
                {"candy":"laffytaffy","timestamp":1385504260,"color":"blue"}]';

$decodedJson = array();
$decodedJson = json_decode($jsonData);

print_r ($decodedJson);
?>
```